# JSP changes not being shown in jBoss

Tags: java, jsp, jboss

I am pretty new to jBoss and JSP and come from a PHP background, if that helps.

I have checked out a project from subversion and am fooling around with the .jsp pages, tinkering with texts and changing them to get a hang on the screen. Once I do that, I build the project again, the changes I made on the *.jsp pages do not reflect on the screen. Do I need to stop, restart jBoss and then build the project again ? (that would be crazy)

Not sure what I am missing out, but any explanation is welcome.

Comment: You probably need to _re-deploy_ the app after you _re-build_ it.

Comment: so technically, each time I make a trivial change to my application, I need to keep re-deploying it over n over again ?

Comment: If you're only working with front end files (_JSPs_ for example) you could also copy the modified file(s) into the deployment directory of your application server.  Consult your app server's documentation for more info about how to do this.

Comment: Which IDE are you using to change the JSPs?  In case of Eclipse, if other options don't help, try using FileSync plugin - [link](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/filesync/)

Answer (score 3):

By default if you deploy an exploded Web application (not packaged but as a folder) the content is automatically reloaded each time you modify a JSP. 
You can alter this behaviour using specific configuration for the JBoss AS release you are using. For example, if you are using JBoss AS 7, then check this [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web-server/how-to-deploy-a-web-application-on-the-root-context-on-jboss-as-7). 
Hope it helps